# how to maximize browser window in selenium webdriver 3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I gone through lots of tutorial but not getting proper solution for this error

> TypeError: maximize_window() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: How did you call it? post the code.

Answer (score 0):

`from selenium import webdriver`

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.maximize_window()`

This works just fine, assuming you have downloaded chromedriver.

You can also download geckodriver and work with Firefox, personally i prefer this.